# How to use PowerShell to find a DWORD in the registry and change the value. The DWORD could be in several keys and not known ahead of time

Tags: powershell, registry

I am new to Powershell and not sure how to go about this.  I have at least got it to identify the DWORD I am looking for.  I can also set a value if I know the location.  Just not sure how to combine the two of searching and updating.

```
$path="HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\" 
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-ItemProperty -name Foundit -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object{$_.Foundit -eq 22}

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\Test\1" -Name Foundit -Value '21'
```

Comment: Just pipe the `Set-ItemProperty` at the end of the command before it:

`Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-ItemProperty -name Foundit -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object{$_.Foundit -eq 22} | Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\Test\1" -Name Foundit -Value '21'`

Comment: Sorry, I manually added the path on my example. How do I get the path that is retrieved on the get-ItemProperty

Comment: Do you mean something like `$myVar = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`? If you just want the string path, there are a number of ways to parse that in PowerShell.

If you knew the first result would always be the target you're after:

`$(Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\" ).Name | Select -First 1` and you could save that to a variable for later use.

If the results could be varied, you could use a match operator:

`$(Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\" ).Name | Where {$_.Name -match "your match string here"}`

Comment: Let me give a better example.  the root path will always be "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\" .  Then I might have a key called 1 and another called K under that root.  Each of these will have a key called Foundit.  So I do not know ahead of time what the keys past the root will be.  I just need to be able to -recurse past the root and see if there is a DWORD called Foundit.  If there is I need to change the value to 0.

Comment: Then you'll need to `Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\" -Recurse` and then find a means to sort the results, or if you need to change every instance of that key file, use a `foreach()` or `for()` loop with a `Where {$_.Name -match FoundIt}` or similar

Answer (score 0):

```
$DWordName = "MSIP.OutlookAddin"
$Locations = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList"

foreach($location in $locations)

{

try {if((get-itempropertyvalue -path $location -name $DWordName) -eq ""){write-host "Value doesn't exists"}}

catch {New-ItemProperty -Path $Location -Name $DWordName -Value "1" -Type DWord}

if((get-itempropertyvalue -path $location -name $DWordName) -eq "1"){write-host "Value already exists"}

else {Set-ItemProperty -Path $Location -Name $DWordName -Value "1" -Type DWord}

}
```